# Append Lines using BufferedReader and FileWriter

Tags: java, append, bufferedreader, filewriter

I'm trying to parse the code in a file and copy it to a newly created file with the relevant modifications.

However, in the new file all that appears is the final line from the original file.

How do I ensure all the lines get copied to the new file, and not just the last one?

Note: I want a new file to be created every time I run this program, so this question isn't about the FileWriter constructor with 'true' passed in as shown below

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile.txt, true);
```

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(myNewFile.txt)) {

        while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
            String currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            fileWriter.write(currentLine);
        }
```

myNewFile.txt only contains the last line of text from the file passed in to the BufferedReader. I don't know of any append functions provided by the FileWriter class.

Thanks

EDIT (SOLUTION):

The problem was resulting from the initialization of currentLine in the while loop. I changed it to

```
String currentLine;
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    fileWriter.write(currentLine);
}
```

Comment: How many lines does your starting file have? You might prefer using the append() method, inherited by Writer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You are **not** giving all relevant pieces of code. For example it is not obvious if you ever close() your writer. Beyond that: such questions come up almost daily. Did you do some research and had a look into all the questions that explain how to use a filewriter, and how to create "modified copied" of text files?

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for getting back. I believe all the info you're asking for is included. I don't close the writer because it's in a try-with-resources block. I appreciate the feedback, but I think I have clearly stated what my problem is (although I have slightly edited the original question to be more specific)

Answer (score 0):

```
new FileWriter(myNewFile.txt, true)
```

This enable the append mode